# edited: why does comparison test for series not apply to series which arent necessarily made up of all non negative terms?

Tags: calculus, analysis

I mean if $a_k>b_k$ for every k and we know the sum of b_k diverges, ie the sequence of partial sums of b_k go to infinity, then since each a_k>b_k, the partial sums of a_k are always bigger than those of b_k, hence the partial sums of a_k should go to infinity as well? Thanks.

edit: by sum of b_k diverges I mean assuming the sum of b_k is infinity. i dont see how sum a_k can be anything other than infinity in this case as well.

Answer (score 1):

Easy to see that $\sum 0$ converges, and
$$
0 = \sum 0 \geqslant \sum -n^{-1}, 0 \geqslant \sum -n^{-2}, 
$$
but $\sum -n^{-1} = -\infty$, $\sum -n^{-2} = - \sum n^{-2}$ converges.

Comparison test works because the sequence of partial sums are monotonically increasing, so when $0\leqslant  a_n \leqslant b_n$, the partial sums $A_n \leqslant B_n$, then when $\sum b_n$ converges, $B_n < +\infty$ implies $A_n < +\infty$, and $A_n$ converges because it is bounded above by $\sum b_n$.

### UPDATE

Divergence does not only mean that the partial sum goes to infinity, a typical counterexample is $1-1+1-1+1-1+\cdots$: the partial sums are bounded by $1$. If you know that $B_n \to +\infty$, then you could conclude that $A_n \to +\infty$ given that $a_n \geqslant b_n$. Otherwise you should  not conclude anything before you investigate $b_n, a_n$ further.

Comment: Thanks, I understand that direction but not the direction I presented of divergence..

Comment: ie if the terms of your series are bigger than those that form a series that goes to infinity, why wouldn't your series also go to infinity?

Comment: What if the infinity is $-\infty$? $\sum 0=0, \sum 1/n =+\infty$, and suppose $b_n =-1$, then $a_n = (-1)^n \geqslant b_n$ but $\sum a_n$ diverges and it is not $\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the sequences

$a_k=\frac{{(-1)}^{k+1}}{k}$ $, k\in \mathbb{N}$

$b_k= \begin{cases} -1,& \text{if k is even } \\ 0, & \text{if k is odd } \end{cases}$

Here $a_k > b_k$ $\forall k\in \mathbb{N}$

Also, $\sum_{k=1}^\infty b_n$ is not convergent here but $ \sum_{k=1}^\infty  a_k$ is convergent

This shows why comparison test not applicable when terms are non-negative.
However, it is applicable in case if all but finitely many terms are non-negative.